# Remove element in array / swapping values

Tags: c, arrays

I am dynamicly allocating and reallocating 2d array. I am searching for the match in array and if i find the match , i want to delete index where the match is found , how can i achieve so? For illustration (withou dynamicly allocating ) lets assume i have an array and i am searching for the match in it .

```
int arr [2][2]={{12,2},{1,2}}
for ( int i =0; i < 2 ; i++){
  if ( arr[i][0]=1 && arr[i][1]=2){
  // remove item from array;
}
}
```

how can i achieve such thing?
On another note how could i swap values of 2d array( dynamicly allocated)
example > array looks like

```
{
{5,5},
{6,6},
{7,7}
}
```

and i want it to look like

```
{
    {7,7},
    {6,6},
    {5,5}
    }
```

how can i achieve it with 2d arrays? I have tried

```
                            int ag=arr[bestDeal]; //bestdeal is matched index
                            arr[bestDeal]=ponuka[0];
                            arr[0]=ag;
```

But it didnt work
full example

```
while(scanf("%s %d%d",&znak,&X,&Y)!=EOF){

            if(znak=='+'){
                if(index==number){
                    size_t newnum = (number + 2) * 2;
                    int **tmp=(int **)realloc(ponuka, newnum * sizeof(*ponuka));
                    number=newnum;
                    ponuka=tmp;
            } // allocating array
            ponuka[index]=(int *)malloc(2 * sizeof ( int )); // 2nd dimension
            ponuka[index][0]=X;
            ponuka[index][1]=Y;
            index++;
            }
            else{

                    int first=1;
                    int match=0;
                    int bestDeal;
                    int tmp;
                    for (i = ass; i < index; i++){
                       if(ponuka[i][0]==X && ponuka[i][1]<=Y && ponuka[i][1]>0){
                            if(first){tmp=ponuka[i][1];}
                            if(ponuka[i][1]<=tmp){
                                tmp=ponuka[i][1];
                                bestDeal=i;
                            } // found match and assign index into variable;;
                        match=1;
                       }

                    }


                            int gg=ponuka[bestDeal];
                            ponuka[bestDeal]=ponuka[0];
                            ponuka[0]=gg;

                            ass++; // trying to swap values and incrementing looping so matches values will be at start and loop wont go through them


                    }

            }
    }
```

Comment: How do you think it could be done? Please give it a try yourself first. By the way, `=` is the assignment operator but you want the comparisson operator, `==`.

Comment: updated with my attempt

Comment: That;s not much of code. Show us a complete example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this example....You will get an idea.......

```
int main()
{
   int array[100], position, c, n;

   printf("Enter number of elements in array\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   printf("Enter %d elements\n", n);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      scanf("%d", &array[c]);

   printf("Enter the location where you wish to delete element\n");
   scanf("%d", &position);

   if ( position >= n+1 )
      printf("Deletion not possible.\n");
   else
   {
      for ( c = position - 1 ; c < n - 1 ; c++ )
         array[c] = array[c+1];

      printf("Resultant array is\n");

      for( c = 0 ; c < n - 1 ; c++ )
         printf("%d\n", array[c]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: this would be very slow if my array had 1k+ items

Answer (score 0):

The following code will likely do what you want:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
int main()
{
    // Current size of array.
    int size = 4;
    int size2D = 2;
    // Number that we want to find.
    int numToFind[2] = {1, 1};
    int **a = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size2D);
        a[i][0] = i;
        a[i][1] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (a[i][0] == numToFind[0] && a[i][1] == numToFind[1])
        {
            // Found number, move all the elements to the right of this element 
            // one step left.
            memmove(&a[i], &a[i + 1], sizeof(int*)*(size-i));

            // Reduce array size by 1.
            a = (int**)realloc(a, sizeof(int*)*(size - 1));
            size--;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", a[i][0], a[i][1]);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLS 2

void print(int **arr, int rows);
void swap_row(int **r1, int **r2);

int main(void){
    //{{5,5}, {6,6}, {1,2}, {7,7}}
    int rows = 4;
    int **arr = malloc( rows * sizeof(*arr));
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        arr[r] = malloc( COLS * sizeof(**arr));
    }
    memcpy(arr[0], (int[COLS]){5,5}, sizeof(int[COLS]));
    memcpy(arr[1], (int[COLS]){6,6}, sizeof(int[COLS]));
    memcpy(arr[2], (int[COLS]){1,2}, sizeof(int[COLS]));
    memcpy(arr[3], (int[COLS]){7,7}, sizeof(int[COLS]));

    print(arr, rows);

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        if(!memcmp(arr[r], (int[COLS]){1,2}, sizeof(int[COLS]))){
            free(arr[r]);
            memmove(&arr[r], &arr[r+1], (rows - (r+1)) * sizeof(*arr));
            --rows;
            break;
        }
    }
    print(arr, rows);//{{5,5}, {6,6}, {7,7}}

    swap_row(&arr[0], &arr[2]);
    print(arr, rows);//{{7,7}, {6,6}, {5,5}}

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        free(arr[r]);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}

void print(int **arr, int rows){
    puts("{");
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        printf("\t{");
        for(int c = 0; c < COLS; ++c){
            if(c)
                putchar(',');
            printf("%d", arr[r][c]);
        }
        printf("}%s", (r != rows -1) ? ",\n" : "\n");
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

void swap_row(int **r1, int **r2){
    int *temp = *r1;
    *r1 = *r2;
    *r2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: can i do that without knowing the value of index i wanna swap? You are declaring  memcpy(arr[0], (int[COLS]){5,5}, sizeof(int[COLS]));
    memcpy(arr[1], (int[COLS]){6,6}, sizeof(int[COLS]));
    memcpy(arr[2], (int[COLS]){1,2}, sizeof(int[COLS]));
    memcpy(arr[3], (int[COLS]){7,7}, sizeof(int[COLS])); with exact value .

Comment: _can i do that without knowing the value of index i wanna swap?_ use variable E.g `swap_row(&arr[r1], &arr[r2]);`